# UnicodeDecodeError when reading SPSS dataset with python

Tags: python, spss

I am trying to write a syntax in SPSS to modify values. When I try to read my dataset, it can read the first 243 entries, but the fails with a reading error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 253: unexpected end of data
```

My code:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import json, re, spss

spss.StartDataStep()
datasetObj = spss.Dataset()
for i in range(len(datasetObj.cases)):
   print datasetObj.cases[i,0]
spss.EndDataStep()

END PROGRAM.
```

How can I read the current dataset without errors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that error trying this in V24.  0xc3 is capital A with tilde, but it appears that the code is expecting utf-8.  That letter would be C383 in utf-8.

Are you in Unicode mode or code page mode (SHOW UNICODE)?  If code page, what is your locale (SHOW LOCALE).  What version of Statistics and what platform?

If you are not in Unicode mode, try changing to that with SET UNICODE ON or via Edit > Options > Language.

Also, where exactly does the error arise?  There should be a traceback with the error display.  Change the code to this
x = datasetObj.cases[i,0]
print x

to make the location of the error clearer.

Comment: The Unicode "code point" of A with tilde (&#xc3;)  is `U+00C3`. However, the OP's error says `0xc3`, which is a partial hexadecimal UTF-8 code. Strip away `0x` and you're left with `c3`; not a character by itself. The &#xc3; in UTF-8 encoding is `C383` or better: `0xC3 0x83`. Likewise, capital O with stroke (&#xd8;) is `0xC3 0x98`. Conclusion: a UTF-8 code `0xC3` is always followed by another code. Just `0xC3` is no character, so cannot be decoded. `0xC3` is used for an extended Latin letters set.
[This list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) is nice for reference.